# Animating the Layout

Tags: android, animation

I have requirement for my project. I want the  my Relative layout to slide from top to bottom ..Can anyone please give me some help on this

Thanks,
Keerthi

Comment: check This            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374823/android-animate-my-relative-layout-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-using-tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple,

Create a layout  and apply translate animation on the layout. In the XML make the layout invisible and in your code make it visible

Change this XML according to ur need

```
       <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="220dip"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_marginTop="480dip"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code is like this

```
         Animation movement5; 
  layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);


              layout3.setVisibility(true); USE THIS LINE //EDITED

 movement5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.layout.animation_test5);
    movement5.reset();
        movement5.setfillafter(true);
    movement5.setAnimationListener(this);
         layout3.startAnimation(movement5);
```

animation_test5.xml .

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="-300%"
  android:toYDelta="100%" android:duration="3000" android:zAdjustment="normal" />
```

Comment: movement.setAnimationListener(this);...Iam getting the error for setAnimationListener.. Can u tell me what is this object

Comment: Your activity should implement AnimationListner

Comment: But when I do that it asks me to add unimplemented methods.. after adding those methods should I edit those methods..

Comment: not necessary to edit the methods, if it works correctly just accept the anwer thats it ,good luck :)

Comment: Animation movement;
 
 RelativeLayout layout;
 layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

 
 movement=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation_test5);
 movement.reset();
 movement.setFillAfter(true);
 movement.setAnimationListener(this); 
 
 layout.startAnimation(movement); this is what I do.. and not getting the result..

Comment: Hi, it works proper for me.. But the thing is that the screen slides down and disappear..where as I want the screen to slide down and remain visible there.. any help on this ?

Comment: use layout.setVisibility(true);  see the edited code above it works

Comment: and also in onendAnimation() method use setFillAfter(true);

Comment: @Raghav : When I want to do down at that what I have to do changes  mean after visible when click on button it disappear but with down to top effect  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the class TranslateAnimation

```
public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

Here you can give values for fromYDelta and toYDelta for top to bottom animation. And call the methods setDuration(time in milliseconds) and setFillAfter(true) by the object of the class TranslateAnimation.