# Android animate my Relative Layout from bottom to Top and Top to Bottom using translate animation on image view click

Tags: android, android-animation

I Need to make animate my Relative Layout when click on image view..

1.Moving Relative Layout from Bottom to Top (when clicking him on image view).

2.Moving back from Top to Bottom (when clicking him again on image view).

First when i click on image view it's works fine and Relative Layout move up from bottom to top, but when i click again on image view it's animate from top to bottom, when it's reached to the original position it's hide on my activity..any help and Thanks in advance.

This is my Activity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    iv_header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            // iv_header.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // iv_down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); // substitute parameters for
                                                // left, top, right, bottom
            rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_manu_bar);
            // FooterAnimation();

            if (isBottom) {
                FooterAnimation();
                isBottom = false;
            } else {
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_manu_bar1);
                headerAnimation();
                isBottom = true;
            }

        }
    });

}

public void FooterAnimation() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            if (isBottom) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                lp.setMargins(rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            } else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

        }

    });

}

public void headerAnimation() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            if (isBottom) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                lp.setMargins(rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            } else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

and my Xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/autograph_bg" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/down_manu_bar1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:onClick="onNewFileClick"
        android:src="@drawable/file_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:text="New"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:src="@drawable/insert_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_save"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Layout Animations from bottom to top and top to bottom on imageview click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have solved my issue and now my animation works fine :)
if anyone needed just copy my code and xml and plz don't thanks :p

My Activity MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    iv_header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); 
            rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_manu_bar);
            if (isBottom) {
                SlideToAbove();
                isBottom = false;
            } else {
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_manu_bar1);
                SlideToDown();
                isBottom = true;
            }

        }
    });

}

public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

and my Xml activity_main:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rl_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/autograph_bg" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/down_manu_bar1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:onClick="onNewFileClick"
        android:src="@drawable/file_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_new_file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:text="New"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_new_file"
        android:src="@drawable/insert_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_insert"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_save"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_save"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_settings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

just create new android project and copy paste my code and have fun! :)
also remember in xml i have image view and his background images replace with yout own images thanks..

Comment: will it work like an image falling from top to bottom and disappear @Farhan Shah

Comment: in my case realtivelayout just blink once

Comment: @Ramani in my case it's working fine, when u click on relative layout the layout animate from bottom to top,and when click again on the relative layout the layout successfully going down from top to bottom. plz check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323628/android-layout-animations-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-on-imageview-clic/22370395?noredirect=1#comment49779551_22370395