# Animation not working in Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have 4 layout in one activity and layout is working properly. I want when i am checking check-box then its hide 3rd layout and 4th layout slides up and replace 3rd layout and when unchecked check-box then 3rd layout visible 4th slide down and set proper position.

> but its not working properly...

**MyCode**

```
 checklayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_check);
    promolayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.promo_layout);
    _Payment_full=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pay_full);
        _CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_wallet);
        _CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    promolayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    _Payment_full.startAnimation(slide_up);
                    _Payment_full.animate()
                            .translationYBy(100)
                            .translationY(0)
                            .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
                    String url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
                    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {

                                        JSONObject json_Response = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String _RchAmount = json_Response.getString("pay_from_wallet");
                                        String _Remainbalance = json_Response.getString("ewalletbalance");
                                        String _InrPay = json_Response.getString("amt_collected");
                                        confirm_payWallet.setText("Pay from Yup Wallet Rs. " + _RchAmount);
                                        confirm_TotalWallet.setText("Your current wallet balance is Rs." + _Remainbalance);
                                        total_pay.setText("Rs. " + _InrPay);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Log.d("checked in wallet", "------>" + response);
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.e("Checked err error==", "===>" + error);
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }) {

                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            MyApplication uid = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                            String user = uid.getuser();
                            MyApplication _tansId = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                            String trans_id = _tansId.getTransaction();
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("akey", "XXXXXX");
                            params.put("userid", user);
                            params.put("transid", trans_id);
                            params.put("ewallet_checkbox", "on");

                            Log.i(TAG, "Sending Value" + params);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    newApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
                  }
                else
                 {
                    promolayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    _Payment_full.startAnimation(slide_down);
                     _Payment_full.animate()
                         .translationYBy(0)
                         .translationY(100)
                         .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
                    String url = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
                    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {

                                        JSONObject json_Response = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String _RchAmount = json_Response.getString("pay_from_wallet");
                                        String _Remainbalance = json_Response.getString("ewalletbalance");
                                        String _InrPay = json_Response.getString("amt_collected");
                                        confirm_payWallet.setText("Pay from Yup Wallet Rs. " + _RchAmount);
                                        confirm_TotalWallet.setText("Your current wallet balance is Rs." + _Remainbalance);
                                        total_pay.setText("Rs. " + _InrPay);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Log.d("checked in wallet", "------>" + response);
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.e("Checked err error==", "===>" + error);
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }) {

                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            MyApplication uid = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                            String user = uid.getuser();
                            MyApplication _tansId = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                            String trans_id = _tansId.getTransaction();
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("akey", "XXXXXX");
                            params.put("userid", user);
                            params.put("transid", trans_id);
                            params.put("ewallet_checkbox", "off");

                            Log.i(TAG, "Sending Value" + params);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    newApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Change the Position in _Payment_full.startAnimation(slide_up); this line first you need to set Duration than start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374823/android-animate-my-relative-layout-from-bottom-to-top-and-top-to-bottom-using-tr

Comment: @koutuk thanks but its going in top of screen Please help me

Answer (score -2):

```
_Payment_full.animate()
             .translationYBy(100)
             .translationY(0)
             .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime)).start();
```

Comment: Please add details explaining your answer.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are generally considered to be of low quality